Using 2 spline paths at once
I'm working on a simple game, and one of the features that I want to have is cars driving across roads. I have been directed to use spline pathing.
The problem I have encountered is that I cannot have two separate actors using two separate spline paths. I can get one to work fine, but not the other.
I can't find anything on the internet, so I can't imagine that it is something that many people have had trouble getting past.
Attached is the blueprints for my working actor. Thanks
(https://i.sstatic.net/nHiKfFPN.png)
I have tried creating 2 spline paths and 2 actors, 1 spline path and 2 actors, 2 spline paths and 1 actor, but nothing has worked.
I was expecting to have 2 actors moving in one direction down both spline paths, which then regenerate at the start and go again.
Instead, I only ever have 1 actor moving down 1 of the spline paths, which then regenerates at the start and goes again.
